# How to create Xcode groups with CMake?

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I have a C++ project split into several nested folders, one per namespace (`internal`, `internal::business_logic_one`, `internal::business_logic_two`).

When I open the project in QTCreator the folder hierarchy is respected and the project makes sense visually, making it easy to navigate.

But when I generate the Xcode project I have a very distinct folder hierarchy where my header and implementation files (.cpp) end up in distinct folders (groups?) that are not related to folder structure of the project.

Is there a way to make Xcode respect that hierarchy?

**Update**

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
if (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there. You may need to remove CMakeCache.txt.")
endif()

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(myproject)

set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR, 0)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR, 1)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH, 0)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_TWEAK, 0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
enable_language(CXX)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
   set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DASIO_STANDALONE -std=c++11")

if (NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pedantic -Wno-padded -Wno-undef -Wno-old-style-cast -gdwarf-2")
endif()

if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Clang")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Weverything -ferror-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-documentation -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-weak-vtables -Wno-global-constructors -Wno-exit-time-destructors")
endif()
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lstdc++")
endif()

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)
#  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING")
  if (NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")
  endif()
  if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Clang")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -glldb")
  endif()
endif()

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.2)
    set(UPDATE_DISCONNECTED_IF_AVAILABLE "")
else()
    set(UPDATE_DISCONNECTED_IF_AVAILABLE "UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1")
endif()

# Build library
set(SOURCE_FILES <my_source_files>)
add_library(myproject STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})
# add_library(myproject SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Can please give a [mcve] of your CMake code and what you have already tried? A guess would be that you are using the `source_group()`. What version of CMake do you use? Does it work with other projects/CMake versions?

Comment: @Florian Added a slightly edited version of my CMakeLists.txt. I do not use source_group().